# How to use logarithmic differentiation in this example (I seem to be going wrong)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm revising for my Calculus & Vectors exam in January, and one of the warm-up questions from a previous problem sheet was to differentiate $e^{-t}*\cosh{t}*\sinh{t}$

This could be done through the product rule but having just practised logarithmic differentiation I thought it might be quicker to do that. However, doing that I get

$$\ln{y}=\ln{e^{-t}}+\ln{(\cosh{t})}+\ln{(\sinh{t})}$$

$$\ln{y}=-t+\ln{(\cosh{t})}+\ln{(\sinh{t})}$$

$$\frac{1}{y}*\frac{dy}{dt} = -1 + \frac{\sinh{t}}{\cosh{t}} + \frac{\cosh{t}}{\sinh{t}}$$

$$\therefore \frac{dy}{dt} = -y + y\tanh{t} + y\coth{t}$$

Which doesn't involve any form of $e$ and is quite a long way away from what wolfram alpha gives too, so my guess is I've gone wrong somewhere! I'm also pretty new to latex so although that looks ok to me, sorry if it doesn't display properly.

Comment: "I'm also pretty new to latex so although that looks ok to me, sorry if it doesn't display properly." Displays okay here. At the very least, it looks a lot better than if you hadn't used it at all.

Comment: Yes, looks fine. You may be pleased to know you can use \cdot to produce the raised dot used for multiplication instead of the asterisk (so you can write $a\cdot b$ instead of $a*b$).

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest way would be to realize that
\begin{equation}
e^{-t}\cdot\cosh t \cdot\sinh t = e^{-t}\cdot\frac{1}{2}(e^t + e^{-t})\cdot \frac{1}{2}(e^t - e^{-t})
=\frac{1}{4}e^t - \frac{1}{4}e^{-3t}
\end{equation}
so that the derivative is just $\frac{1}{4}e^t + \frac{3}{4}e^{-3t}$

Answer (score 1):

At the step
$$
\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}=-1+\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh t} + \frac{\cosh t}{\sinh t}
$$
you can just continue:
$$
f'(t)=-e^{-t}\sinh t\cosh t+e^{-t}\sinh t\cosh t\frac{\sinh t}{\cosh t}
+e^{-t}\sinh t\cosh t\frac{\cosh t}{\sinh t}
$$
and simplify:
$$
f'(t)=e^{-t}(\sinh^2t-\sinh t\cosh t+\cosh^2t).
$$

However, you gain nothing in this case:
$$
f'(t)=-e^{-t}\sinh t\cosh t+e^{-t}\cosh^2t+e^{-t}\sinh^2t
$$
by just applying
$$
(A(t)B(t)C(t))'=A'(t)B(t)C(t)+A(t)B'(t)C(t)+A(t)B(t)C'(t).
$$